# Methods to handle form conflict in field positioning on page

Tags: html, css, forms

I have to make a page that look like painting below, but:

**field 1** and **filed 4** are in one **form** with **submit 2**

**field 2** and **filed 3** are in one (other one) **form** with **submit 1**

Do you know any methods of styling positioning html components to deal with it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code (I agree with Wivlaro )

```
    <form id="form1" action="">
<br/>
    <input type="text" id="field2" value="field2"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="field3"  value="field3"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit 1" />
    </form>

<form id="form2" action="">
    <input type="text" id="field1"  value="field1"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="field4"  value="field4"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit2" value="Submit 2" />   
</form>

<style>
    #field1{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;      
    }
    #form2{
        margin-top:-18px    
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make more sense to have the fields next to their own submit form so that the user's mental model matches the behaviour of the application.

However, if you **must** do this, you could just use some CSS like this for field1 to move it above the other two (as long as the layout is fairly fixed):

```
position:relative;
top: -100px; /* Pick an appropriate number and unit */
```

Then you could give field 1's container some negative top padding or margin to compensate for the missing height.

It's ugly though.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to do it like I have described (that is not decided by me). I have already consider your solution, but I'm sure it will broke it validation messages will pop-up. It can also broke on some IE version. IE have a lot of problems with margins.